# Behavior of the solution to a linear system of differential equations when $t\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

Consider the system of linear DEs given below:
$$ x' =2x+y \\
y' = 3x +4y\\
x(0) =-y(0) = 1.
$$
What would be $L = \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} ||x(t)||$?

**Attempt:** The given system matrix
$\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 1\\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$
has eigenvalues $\lambda = 1,5$ and a corresponding pair of eigenvectors $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 
1\\-1
\end{pmatrix}$ and
$v_5 = \begin{pmatrix} 
1\\3
\end{pmatrix}$. As a result, the general solution may be written as
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
x(t)\\y(t)
\end{pmatrix} = c_1e^t \begin{pmatrix} 
1\\-1
\end{pmatrix} + c_2 e^{5t} \begin{pmatrix} 
1\\3
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Applying the initial conditions leads to
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
x(t)\\y(t) 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
e^t \\ -e^t
\end{pmatrix}.$$

So, naturally, $L = \infty$. However, the solution manual says $L=0$ but I don't understand it's mumbo-jumbo reasoning. Can you help me figure out what's wrong with my solution?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your computations of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues seem correct.

However, the solutions you computed are the good ones in the basis of the eigenvectors. But you forgot to switch back to the canonical basis. For example, the initial conditions are given in the canonical basis.

*Note: you can by the way easily verify that your « solution » of the IVP is in fact not one by computing the derivatives.*